# NSCollectionview didSelectItemsAt never called

Tags: nscollectionview

i'm creating an NSCollectionview without xib/storyboard, when touched item, collectionView:didSelectItemsAt: method never called. z_setupView()  called in viewdidload()

/// init collectionview

```
fileprivate func z_setupView() {
    view.addSubview(topCollectionView)
    topCollectionView.delegate = self
    topCollectionView.dataSource = self
    let flLayout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
    topCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flLayout
    topCollectionView.register(BannerCollectionItem.self, forItemWithIdentifier: "BannerCollectionItem")

    topCollectionView.snp.remakeConstraints {[weak self] (make) in
        make.top.equalTo((self?.view.snp.top)!).offset(10)
        make.leading.equalTo(0)
        make.trailing.equalTo(0)
        make.height.equalTo(200)
    }
}    
}
```

// here is the NSCollectionViewItem

```
class BannerCollectionItem: NSCollectionViewItem {

 public var bannerModel: BannerAdModel? {
    didSet {
        adImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "a_img_beijin")
        adImageView.frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80)

    }
}
fileprivate var adImageView = NSImageView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func touchesBegan(with event: NSEvent) {
    debugPrint("BannerCollectionItem touchesBegan")
}
override func loadView() {
    self.view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
    self.view.addSubview(adImageView)

}  
}
```

without xib、sb，how can i call delegate functions ?

Comment: here is my solution： NSCollectionView item could not be selected on default，we must set collectionview `isSelectable` is true     topCollectionView.isSelectable = true

Comment: I tried to line up your first code example, found out that you have extra closing curly braces :)

Comment: You can put your answer as an answer, instead of as a comment ;) @Geezher

Comment: thank you for your response，curly braces maybe cased by 'comment format'  ⚆_⚆

Answer (score 12, accepted):

here is my solution： NSCollectionView item could not be selected on default，we must set

```
collectionview.isSelectable = true
```

Comment: You can also accept the answer ;). If it fixes your problem.